# Where to place the javascript file in codeigniter directory?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, codeigniter

Sorry if this question is a repeat, I have read most of the questions of similar kind but it didn't solve my problem. I have this code for dependent drop down list using angular js, where I am trying to implement in my codeigniter project. When I place this codes directly into my view form.php I get the result as expected.

```
script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function CountryController($scope) {
            $scope.countries = {
                'India': {
                    'Andhra Pradesh': ['Vijayawada', 'Guntur', 'Nellore', 'Kadapa'],
                    'Madhya Pradesh': ['Hyderabad', 'Warangal', 'Karimnagar'],  
                },
                'USA': {
                  'San Francisco': ['SOMA', 'Richmond', 'Sunset'],
                  'Los Angeles': ['Burbank', 'Hollywood']
                },
                'Australia': {
                    'New South Wales': ['Sydney','Orange','Broken Hill'],
                    'Victoria': ['Benalla','Melbourne']
                }
            };
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div ng-app class="container">
      <div ng-controller="CountryController">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="Country">Country:</label>
          <select class="form-control input-lg" id="country" ng-model="states" ng-options="country for (country, states) in countries">
            <option value=''>Select</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="States">States:</label>
          <select class="form-control input-lg" id="state" ng-disabled="!states" ng-model="cities" ng-options="state for (state,city) in states">
            <option value=''>Select</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="City">City:</label>
          <select class="form-control input-lg" id="city" ng-disabled="!cities || !states" ng-model="city" ng-options="city for city in cities">
            <option value=''>Select</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I want to place the javascript codes into >MyProject>js directory and copy pasted the javascript into a file called script.js and included the following line into 
view/includes/header.php

```
script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/script.js"></script>
```

In my controller>form.php I have a line to load the header.php

```
$this->load->view('includes/header',$datah);
```

When I separate the script from view>form.php I only get the drop down list which is the result of the html tags that I have but there are no contents or list of countries or cities to be seen in any of the drop down menu. Please somebody help me find what has gone wrong with my attempt.

Comment: truthfully I have tried using Angular together with a PHP framework in the past and I find it pointless. It actually made me go against Angular. is there a reason you need angular? you can easily do all this with jQuery alone.

Comment: @CodeGodie no reason at all, I just found this code and tried to use it in my project. Ill go for jQuery as you suggested. But this functionality was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Typically angular js code goes at the end of your html file just before the </body> tag.  That way, all the html is loaded before angular kicks off.  Try moving your script tags to your footer file.

Comment: not working @cerad gave it a try. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would do away with Angular. I would build the array in my CI controller, then pass it to the view. The view will then use jquery to do the work in a separate JS file:

**Controller:**

```
function method() {
    $data['countries'] = array(
        'India' => array(
            'Andhra Pradesh' => array('Vijayawada', 'Guntur', 'Nellore', 'Kadapa'),
            'Madhya Pradesh' => array('Hyderabad', 'Warangal', 'Karimnagar'),
        ),
        'USA' => array(
            'San Francisco' => array('SOMA', 'Richmond', 'Sunset'),
            'Los Angeles' => array('Burbank', 'Hollywood'),
        ),
        'Australia' => array(
            'New South Wales' => array('Sydney', 'Orange', 'Broken Hill'),
            'Victoria' => array('Benalla', 'Melbourne'),
        )
    );

    $this->load->view('page', $data);
}
```

**View:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?= base_url();?>js/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="Country">Country:</label>
                <select class="form-control input-lg" id="country">
                    <option value=''>Select</option>
                    <?php foreach ($countries as $country => $states) { ?>
                        <option data-states='<?= json_encode($states); ?>'><?= $country ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="States">States:</label>
                <select class="form-control input-lg" id="state">
                    <option value=''>Select</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="City">City:</label>
                <select class="form-control input-lg" id="city">
                    <option value=''>Select</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#country").change(function() {
        $("#state, #city").html("<option value=''>Select</option>");
        var states = $('option:selected', this).data('states');
        $.each(states, function(k, v) {
            $("#state").append("<option data-cities='" + JSON.stringify(v) + "'>" + k + "</option>");
        });
        $("#state").change(function() {
            var cities = $('option:selected', this).data('cities');
            $.each(cities, function(k, v) {
                $("#city").append("<option>" + v + "</option>");
            });
        });
    });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks @CodeGodie, I have about 20 countries do I create 20 arrays for that or use a database instead

Comment: it would be better to use a database, then you would use a model to retrieve that info, pass it to your controller, then to your view.

Comment: actually, if you will use a database, your best bet is to use AJAX. You will need to create a table for countries with a unique ID, a table for states with a unique ID and a foreign ID to the respective country. Then in AJAX, you will need to call each state/city on change. Let me know if you need help with this, I can probably help you remotely.

Comment: Thank you for your help and your willingness to help me further, it definitely encourages me to learn more and help me learn concepts that I do not know. I have created the database as  you have instructed

Comment: Thats awesome, im glad I can inspire you that way. I am available to help you remotely, perhaps through Teamviewer. Let me know if you need more help with this.

Comment: Alright CodeGodie, first I am trying to implement your codes in my project, I do get the output, but it do not show any country or cities, because I have a huge php files in my project and I get lost where to paste ur codes